# Kubuntu installer changing partition table for unused disk?

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, kubuntu, external-hdd, partition-table

I'm trying to install Kubuntu 20.04 from a USB key to an external (USB) hard drive. The system I'm using to do the installation is an Arch Linux that I'd like to leave untouched. The disk setup looks like this:

```
/dev/nvme0n1 : used in Arch (LEAVE UNTOUCHED)
/dev/sda : used in Arch (LEAVE UNTOUCHED)
/dev/sdb : used in Arch (LEAVE UNTOUCHED)
/dev/sdc1 : efi for Kubuntu (USE)
/dev/sdc2 : swap for Kubuntu (USE)
/dev/sdc3 : / for Kubuntu (USE -- format ext4)
```

There's a swap partition on sda as well as an efi partition on nvme0n1 that I had to manually mark "do not use". There's also an ext4 partition on sda that was already set to "do not use". I have "Device for boot loader installation" set to `/dev/sdc`

This is all fine, but then I click "Install Now" and get the usual warning that data will be destroyed on removed/formatted partitions)... and it says:

```
The partition tables of the following devices are changed:

SCSI3 (0,0,0) (sda)
SCSI8 (0,0,0) (sdc)
```

Why does it want to mess with my sda partition table?

I undid my changes and went through this process a second time to make sure I'm not doing anything with sda other than marking its swap partition "do not use". The full partition table for sda is:

```
/dev/sda:
free space                 1 MB
/dev/sda2     linux-swap   68719 MB
/dev/sda1     ext4         3832066 MB
```

Comment: Ubuntu Ubiquity installer always uses first ESP. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379
Most suggest either disconnecting all other drives either physically or logically in UEFI settings, or some have had removing boot/esp flag from first drive, so then ESP on external drive is used. I always check mounts before partitioning table changes & again on username & PW screen to see what is mounted.

Comment: Thanks. I got impatient and just did it, and Arch seems OK, but the Ubuntu boot loader stuff got installed to nvme0n1 even though I explicitly marked it "do not use" and had told it to install to sdc. I'll see about disabling my various Arch disks.

Comment: If you have ESP on external drive, you can reinstall grub to that drive & update fstab (grub may do that with the reinstall, but check).